# R-markdown: Generate word document for many names

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am generating word documents based on my data frame. But I want to use two columns as parameters. How do I create separate reports for John(Italy) and John(UK) etc.

```
mydata<-
id employee country val1 val2 val3
1 John Italy 2 4 5
2 John UK 5 6 8
3 Mary USA 2 3 6
4 Andy Germany 5 6 7
5 Andy USA 7 8 9

rmarkdown::render
names <-c("John", "Mary", "Andy")
lapply(names, function(x) rmarkdown::render("template.Rmd", output_file = paste0("Employee-", x,), params = list(employee = x)))
```

Rmd:

````
---
title: "Employee"
author: "Rita"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: word_document
params:
  employee: null 
  country: null
   
---


```{r, setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

Country: `r params$country`

Emp: `r params$employee`

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment='\t', results='asis'}
cat(sprintf("Your employee, %s  from %s worked with %s mydata$val1 clients for %s hours", mydata$employee, mydata$country, mydata$val1, mydata$val2 ))
```
````

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` based on IDs rather than names, even if the ID parameter isn't used by the document.

i. e.

```
mydata<-
id employee country val1 val2 val3
1 John Italy 2 4 5
2 John UK 5 6 8
3 Mary USA 2 3 6
4 Andy Germany 5 6 7
5 Andy USA 7 8 9

rmarkdown::render
ids <- mydata$id
lapply(ids, function(x) rmarkdown::render("template.Rmd", output_file = paste0("Employee-", x,), params = list(employee = x)))
```

Comment: How can we do it in the absense of a record id?

Comment: use any other column, but don't hard code in the unique names. using `ids <- mydata$employee` works just as well

Comment: instead of ids <- mydata$id I did ids <-c("1", "2", "5"). But this does not write the "Country: `r params$country` & Emp: `r params$employee`" information to the output document

Comment: This doesn't work : unexpected input in "apply(mydata, c(1,2), \"

Comment: Misread the docs, passing `1` to `apply`, as in `apply(mydata, 1, some_function)` will apply that function to all rows. you can use the `\(x){}` notation to create your function, or even define it elsewhere. Now it's just a matter of creating the correct function to generate your rmd file. See [this resource about the apply command](https://www.guru99.com/r-apply-sapply-tapply.html) and [this resource about the slash functions](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-use-the-new-function-symbol-in-r-programming-4-1-r-4-1-c7cd2ac27b98)